# Trouble in MVVM tracking viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My requirement is track down the changes happening in datacontext,and when property changes i've added the new viewmodel as history item.first time it work correctly,when made second change that second is also reflecting in History's already added item.What i am doing wrong please help.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<Employee> history;

    public List<Employee> History
    {
        get { return history; }
        set { history = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        History = new List<Employee>();
        this.DataContext = new Employee();
        if (DataContext != null)
        {
            this.DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(MainWindow_DataContextChanged);
            (this.DataContext as Employee).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(MainWindow_PropertyChanged);
        }
    }

    private void MainWindow_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        History.Add((Employee)this.DataContext);
    }

    private void MainWindow_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Employee> history;

    public List<Employee> History
    {
        get { return history; }
        set { history = value; }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    private string ph;

    public string PH
    {
        get { return ph; }
        set { ph = value; RaisePropertyChanged("PH"); }
    }

    private DateTime dob;

    public DateTime DOB
    {
        get { return dob; }
        set { dob = value; RaisePropertyChanged("DOB"); }
    }

    private int age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Age"); }
    }

    public Employee()
    {
        History = new List<Employee>();
        Name = "MKumar";
        Age = 10;
        DOB = new DateTime(2004, 7, 8);
        PH = "999999999";
        PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Employee_PropertyChanged);
    }

    private void Employee_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        History.Add(this);
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal  as your object is a `reference type`. You should make a `deep copy`  in  order to reflect the changments in your history list

try something like  this

```
private void Employee_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var  empCloned = DeepClone(this); 
    History.Add(empCloned);
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

**Deep Copy**

```
private T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
        ms.Position = 0;

        return (T) formatter.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be the coolest thing I will learn today! Thank you, K-B!

For the OP (Kumar) -- make sure the class you use it on is serializable ;)